# Django Postgre ProgrammingError Sum(text)

Tags: python, django

I switched from sqlite to postgresql. postgresql working and everything works just fine. But after switched i take these error;

ProgrammingError...
Error:  sum(text) function is not available.

LINE 1: ...pollvote"."country", "poll_pollvote"."votecount", SUM("poll_...

When i remove this code in template error is gone;

```
                                        {% for vote in votes %}
                                            {% if vote.country == data.country %}
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th scope="row">{{ vote.vote }}</th>
                                                    <td>{{ vote.votecount__sum }}</td>
                                                    <td>{{ vote.votecount__sum|div:data.votecount__sum|mul:100|floatformat }}
                                                        %
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
```

I think my problem these code sum value;

```
result = PollVote.objects.filter(title_id=view.id).values('vote', 'country', 'votecount').annotate(Sum('vote'), Sum(
        'votecount')).order_by('-votecount__sum')
```

When i remove 'vote' value code is start working. How can i use SUM func in 'vote' ?

Comment: It looks like `vote` is not an `IntegerField`, but a `TextField`/`CharField`/..., so you can not sum that.

Comment: Thank you. Yes its not IntegerField but its works good in sqlite3 db. How can i solve this problem? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this problem.

```
result = PollVote.objects.filter(title_id=view.id).values('vote', 'country', 'votecount').annotate(Sum('vote'), Sum(
        'votecount')).order_by('-votecount__sum')
```

change to

```
result = PollVote.objects.filter(title_id=view.id).values('vote', 'country', 'votecount').annotate(Count('vote'), Sum(
        'votecount')).order_by('-votecount__sum')
```

dont forget import Count to head

```
from django.db.models import Count
```